# Java ActionListener buttonPress() restriction

Tags: java, actionlistener

Is there a way to restrict this button to only being impressed once?  The reason I ask is because for some reasons every time the button is pressed it disrupts the rest of my code.  So in effort to save a massive amount of time debugging, it would be much easier to just somehow restrict the number of times it can be pressed.  Thanks in advance.

```
ActionListener pushButton = new buttonPress();
start.addActionListener(pushButton);
```

Comment: It is better to debug it. Could bite you in the a_s later.

Comment: Disable the button on the actionPerformed

Comment: it is homework, so as long as it does what it is suppose to, I'm good.  I realize this isn't how to build maintainable code. @MadProgrammer how do you disable button on actionPerformed?

Comment: @Extinct23 `((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false)` it's a little cheecky and you really should check that the source is an instance of `JButton`, but the idea is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent clicking a button you can use [`JButton.setEnabled(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29). So you could do this as the first statement in your `ActionListener`.

An alternative would be to set a flag in your `ActionListener` like so:

```
final ActionListener pushButton = new ActionListener()
{
    private boolean clicked;
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(clicked)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action already started");
            return;
        }
        clicked = true;
        // ... rest of the action to do ...
    }
}
```

Note that you should not execute long running tasks in your event handler, see [design considerations to keep in mind when implementing event handlers in *The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#design).